# Hibernate Join column annotation refers to which table coulmn

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have gone through some hibernate relation mapping tutorials. It is sort of confusing - hibernate relations.

In first [example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/), both student and department table has a column with name department_id.

[image]

In Student entity,

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="department_id")
private Department department;
```

In department entity,

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
private Set<Employee> employees;
```

1. Which table's column does @JoinColumn refer to?
2. Suppose in deparment table/entity, department_id was named as id, then how will the referencing be done?
3. Also why is department_id column not specified as column in Student entity class?

In second [example](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-many-using-annotations-1.html), i got that (correct me if i am wrong) Student needs a one to many to Phone via Student_Phone while connecting to student_phone using student_id.

[image]

In Student entity,

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_PHONE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PHONE_ID") })
public Set<Phone> getStudentPhoneNumbers() {
    return this.studentPhoneNumbers;
}
```

My question is what is it using inverseJoinColumn. I get it that inverseJoinColumnis somehow used to connect to Phone table. But i would like to

1. How this inverse connection is made?
2. Is it asking Phone to connect to student_phone via phone_id or vice versa?

*The above two examples are just for reference.*

As in [persistence api](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#name%28%29%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B) , it says that the joincolumn references target or source table fk depending on the mapping type.

**It would be helpful if someone could provide an easy way to understand mappings as a whole (with example).**

Comment: It's well-specified in the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#name%28%29. If you need clarification on a specific piece of code, then post that specific piece of code in the question. Not as a link.

Comment: Thank you for link.. i will go through it now..

Answer (score 1):

`1) Which table's column does @JoinColumn refer to?`

It refers to foreign key column in employee table.

`2) Suppose in department table/entity, department_id was named as id, then how will the referencing be done?`

You always go with the foreign key column name, it does not matter to hibernate how your foreign key `references` to your parent table.

`3) Also why is department_id column not specified as column in Employee entity class?`

In a way you already have that mapping, but you have an Object(`Department`) mapping. That's where `ORM` matters. You are referring to Object type of your column.

In the second example, you are using a join table (which can be achieved without joining table just like your first example), you are just describing who is owning the relation (`joinColumn`) and the non-owning side is the `inverseJoinColumn`, just like `mappedBy` in your first example.

Comment: Will the joincolumn always refer to fk of source class?? As in [hibernate api](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#name%28%29) , it says that the joincolumn references target or source table fk depending on the mapping type.

Comment: In your case, it depends on the source table. It depends on the target entity only If you have a uni-directional one-to-many, example: Lets say `Department` has `Set` of employees but `Employee` does not have `Department` then `@JoinColumn` should be on `Set` in `Department` class which will also point to the foreign key column in  `employee` table.